# how to prepare transactional dataset for association rule mining in RapidMiner?

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I have a dataset like this:

```
abelia,fl,nc
esculentus,ct,dc,fl,il,ky,la,md,mi,ms,nc,sc,va,pr,vi
abelmoschus moschatus,hi,pr*
```

[dataset link:](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/plants/)

My dataset haven't any attribute declaration. I want apply association rules on my dataset. I want to be like this dataset.

```
plant   fl  nc  ct  dc  .....
abelia  1   1   0   0
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my work with this python script:

```
import csv

abbrs = ['states', 'ab', 'ak', 'ar', 'az', 'ca', 'co', 'ct',
     'de', 'dc', 'of', 'fl', 'ga', 'hi', 'id', 'il', 'in',
     'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md', 'ma', 'mi', 'mn',
     'ms', 'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj', 'nm', 'ny',
     'nc', 'nd', 'oh', 'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'pr', 'ri', 'sc',
     'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'vi', 'wa', 'wv',
     'wi', 'wy', 'al', 'bc', 'mb', 'nb', 'lb', 'nf', 'nt',
     'ns', 'nu', 'on', 'qc', 'sk', 'yt']

with open("plants.data.txt", encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f1, open("plants.data.csv", "a") as f2:
csv_f2 = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=',')
csv_f2.writerow(abbrs)
csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
for row in csv_f1:
    new_row = [row[0]]
    for abbr in abbrs:
        if abbr in row:
            new_row.append(1)
        else:
            new_row.append(0)
    csv_f2.writerow(new_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

[ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/) contains a **parser** that can read the input as is. Maybe Rapidminer does so, too - or you should write a parser for this format! With the ELKI parameters

```
-dbc.in /tmp/plants.data
-dbc.parser SimpleTransactionParser -parser.colsep ,
-algorithm itemsetmining.associationrules.AssociationRuleGeneration
-itemsetmining.minsupp 0.10
-associationrules.interestingness Lift
-associationrules.minmeasure 7.0
-resulthandler ResultWriter -out /tmp/rules
```

we can find all association rules with support >= 10%, Lift >= 7.0, and write them to the folder /tmp/rules (there is currently **no visualization** of association rules in ELKI):

For example, this finds the rules

```
sc, va, ga: 3882 --> nc, al: 3529 : 7.065536626573297
va, nj: 4036 --> md, pa: 3528 : 7.206260507764794
```

So plants that occur in South Carolina, Virigina, and Georgia will also occur in North Carolina and Alabama. NC is not much of a surprise, given that it is inbetween of SC and VA, but Alabama is interesting.

The second rule is Virigina and New Jersey imply Maryland (inbetween the two) and Pennsylvania. Also a very plausible rule, supported by 3528 cases.

Comment: Thank's Erich. I'm forced to do this in rapidminer. But I do not know how

Comment: I don't use RapidMiner, but I am pretty sure it allows you to write own Java classes, too.

Comment: Although the question is about RapidMiner, your answer saved my day with ELKI!

Answer (score 0):

If all of the values are single words, you can use text mining extension in Rapidminer to transform them into variables and then run association rule mining methods on them.